# Iterative ModExp implementation - Can I replace shiftRight by a Division by 2?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to implement the modExp operator on BigIntegers (I know it already exists, but it's for a presentation only).

So I'm following the pseudocode found on wikipedia:

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    if modulus = 1 then return 0
    Assert :: (modulus - 1) * (modulus - 1) does not overflow base
    result := 1
    base := base mod modulus
    while exponent > 0
        if (exponent mod 2 == 1):
           result := (result * base) mod modulus
        exponent := exponent >> 1
        base := (base * base) mod modulus
    return result
```

So this is what I came up with in Java:

```
static BigInteger modExp(BigInteger x, BigInteger y,  BigInteger m)
{
    if(m.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
        return BigInteger.ZERO;

    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

    x = x.mod(m);

    while(y.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0){
        if (y.mod(TWO).equals(BigInteger.ONE)){
            result = (result.multiply(x)).mod(m);
        }
        y = y.shiftRight(1);

        x = (x.multiply(x).mod(m));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Question: Is it ok to replace the right-shift by a divison by 2 in this case?

Comment: division is generally slower than right-shift. why would you do that?

Comment: Ah ok, so performance is the only difference? I would prefer it because it's easier to explain, and because I wanted to know the difference

Comment: @netik on `unsigned integer` they are the same ... on signed it depends on the used `>>` implementation ... some insert copy of MSB others insert zero ....

Comment: @Spektre: this is Java, so there is no unsigned integer and both the ">>" operator and division are signed, i.e. they always copy the sign bit.